# In $ABC$, $D$ is the feet of the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$. Prove $AB\times AC=BD\times DC+AD^2$

Tags: geometry

[image]

> In $ABC$, $D$ is the feet of the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$.
>  
>   Prove that $AB\times AC=BD\times DC+AD^2$.

I have proved triangles $ABD$ and $ABC$ similar then I am confused.

Comment: In triangles ABD AND ADC, AB/BD=AC/CD AB/BC=AD/BD. AC/BC=AD/DC. SOLVING EQUATIONS I GOT CD(AB+AC)=BD(AC+AD).

Comment: can you post a picture please?

Comment: $ABC$ and $ABD$ are not similar. Hope this helps: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Angle_Bisector

Comment: Already answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844696/finding-the-length-of-the-sections-of-this-side/ (by the OP of that thread himself, by Steven Gregory, and by me).

Answer (score 1):

In the figure below you want to prove $$ab=mn+d^2$$ This is a known theorem about the angle bisector.

HINT.-Draw the circuncircle. By similarity of triangles you get $$ab=d(d+e)$$ and because of the quite known in the circle $$de=mn$$ you can finish.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the [bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) we have:

$$ BD\cdot DC = \frac{ac}{b+c}\cdot \frac{ab}{b+c} = \frac{a^2 bc}{(b+c)^2}\tag{1} $$
and [by Stewart's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Angle_Bisector) we have:
$$ AD^2 = bc-\frac{a^2bc}{(b+c)^2}.\tag{2} $$
The claim readily follows.